# Right alignment in ASPNET + space?

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a field that has a length of 6 and takes in 5 or 6 digit codes.

If a 5 digit code is entered, there needs to be a space in front of the first digit.

Currently I have the text aligned to the right which helps, but is there a way to have any leftover bytes automatically filled with a space?

Comment: ToString() and String.Format has formatting codes you need but please note that, unless font is monospaced, spaces are shorter than digits...

Comment: Note that HTML renders a sequence of whitespace chars as a *single* space, so aligning with spaces may not work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Bind a Javascript event on the onblur event, then modify the content of the TextBox from there.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" onblur="CheckLength()" />
```

Then JS side :

```
function CheckLength() {
    var val = document.getElementById('textbox1').value;
    if (val.length == 5) {
        document.getElementById('textbox1').value = " " + val;
    }
}
```

[EDIT]
If the idea is mainly to show the user that there is a space in front, then instead of changing the value, add a CSS class that will make visual modifications to the textbox (padding-left, textBox background, ...)